# Clustering of high dimensional data

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, unsupervised-learning

I am having a data set with 54 independent variables .Most of them are having zeros it resembles like sparse matrix .**How to cluster this kind of data and is there any data pre processing like Box cox tranformations needed to be done?** Here I am attaching pca plot[image]

Comment: Naive question: could you project to 2D with PCA -- as in your graph, above -- and then use `dbscan` or some other standard clustering in 2D? It sounds like you're looking for a manifold-finding, fancy clustering algorithm but would the simple approach be good enough?

Comment: I tried clustering on 2 levels ,First by SOM and its output is passed to Kmeans.But didn't get considerable results

Comment: OK. The 2D PCA, above, looks like there are clusters -- which may or may not be meaningful in your problem -- and that a density-based approach (say `dbscan`) might be useful. I would tend to avoid K-means because: a) it assumes circular clusters, and b) it's not clear that your problem has a principled K and I'm not a fan of iterating on K to find the best result. Sorry I can't help with more advanced methods.